# Female Villains in The Star Wars Universe

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I'm a Star Wars fan, however my knowledge of Star Wars comes from the movies, not the numerous books, fan websites, and other sources of information that allow one to talk about the Star Wars "Universe."

There have not been any female villains in the Star Wars movies.  We have the Emperor, Darth Vader, Count Dooku, and recently Kylo Ren.

In the Star Wars universe are there female villains and, if so, ones that can be just as uncool as Darth Vader? Or is the Dark Side something into which only men are seduced?

Comment: Does Zam Wesell count as villain enough? She is a bounty hunter...

Comment: Do you want an answer in Disney canon, or Legends/EU canon?  In Legends, Mara Jade was a strong Force user who worked directly for Emperor Palpatine (she was known as the "Emperor's Hand"), doing alot of his "dirty work" for much of her life. She tried to kill Luke several times, but Luke eventually brought her to the light side and made her a Jedi (and his wife).

Comment: @RemyLebeau what's the difference between those two?  Isn't everything Star Wars Universe?

Comment: Captain Phasma is a woman...

Comment: Everything published before Disney bought Lucas's companies fell under various level of canon, loosely managed by Lucas's company with some amount of continuity. They were the "official" stories. Now, there is only Disney canon, everything else (except for the films, TV shows, and a few select books/comics) is no longer canon at all, branded under "Legends".  Basically, Disney wiped the slate clean, threw away most of the existing universe, and started over. [Star Wars canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon)

Comment: @RemyLebeau so if I read a Star Wars book written in 2000 it will be old canon, and that information isn't compatible with Disney's remake?

Comment: @michael_timofeev - some of the information will be compatible, but it isn't guaranteed to be. Fankly, my advice is to read old EU/Legends canon  - which has books that are FAR FAR better quality than new Disney canon books - and not worry too much over "compatible" or "not". Just enjoy good stories and great characters, and don't get upset when new Disney canon contradicts the old pre-Disney EU.

Comment: @WadCheber - She's hardly a villain though. Your traditional villain doesn't immediately surrender when a gun's pointed at them. I'd say that she was more of a goon.

Comment: Did you Google it? You can find a list.

Comment: Star Wars has had a dearth of female *characters* since the beginning.  The original 3 movies had Leia, Luke's aunt, and that one rebel general whose name I forget, and that's pretty much it.  The prequels had Padme and her handmaiden, Anikin's mother, and nobody else.  (There was a female Jedi in III, but she just showed up to die basically.)  Other than that, you've got a few extras and one-line parts, and that's pretty much it for the entire series until Rey showed up.  The Holiday Special had more gender diversity than all 6 movies...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman well that's kind of what I was getting at and was wondering if female villains are a part of the Star Wars universe.  The female storm trooper in the new movie is the closest we have and that wasn't much.  Personally, I'd ,Ike to see some female villains...maybe Rey will fight one in the next movie.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - I think you misunderstood - I was saying that the franchise has had very *few* female characters until Ep. VII.  I basically listed all of 6 in as many movies.  Compare that to the number of male characters, good or evil, and it's clear there was a significant gender-bias all around, not just in the villain department.  It's unfortunately not uncommon.  LotR and The Hobbit combined for example only had 3 women to speak of (Galadriel, Eowyn, and Arwen), and Arwen was barely in the books.  (Tauriel was made up for the films).  Oh, Shelob technically counts as a female villain...

Comment: Since fallen Jedi like Dooku and Atris count, Barriss Offee definitely qualifies, as she does many definitely villainous things.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Lucas canon

Aside from what other answer answers mention:

- [Aurra Sing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurra_Sing), the bounty hunter

### Disney Canon

- First Order's Captain Phasma (she's not as much of a freak as Kylo Ren, but she's quite happy committing and commanding **massacres, genocide and other war crimes**). This is far above and beyond an average Imperial officer.
- Arguably, Captain/Admiral Rae Sloane, though I'd be more hard-pressed to consider her a villain as opposed to simply antagonist.

### EU/Legends

- Irek Ismaren's mother [Roganda](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Roganda_Ismaren) - Emperor's consort and 12BBY conspirator to earn Imperial throne for her son.
- Intelligence Director Ysanne Isard, villain of X-Wing books

  - X-Wing also had a minor female villain, Erine somethingporother.
- [Admiral Daala](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Natasi_Daala), Tarkin's girlfriend, who launched not one but TWO failed attempts to whack the New Republic, one with a brand new planet destroying superwerapon, Sun Crusher.
- Mara Jade was a subversion, set up as Luke's nemesis (she had a mental order from Emperor Palpatine sent moments before DS2 exploded to "kill Luke Skywalker") but later becoming Luke's frenemy, then friend, then wife and his son's mother. She was also very explicitly noted by Luke to have never been on the Dark Side despite serving as Emperor's hand
- [Lumiya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya), Mistress of the Sith
- [Vergere](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vergere), Jedi turned Sith
- [Abeloth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Abeloth), Luke Skywalker's last great antagonist entity.
- [Darth Traya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Traya) of the Old Republic. IIRC there was at least one more female Sith Lord at that time (or even more - [this answer covers Old Republic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113742/976))
- [EV-9D9](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/EV-9D9) was the droid who tortured other droids in Jabba's palace and before that on Cloud City. "Tales from Jabba's palace" paint her as far more of a villain than even the films can.
- [Darth Talon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Talon), serving Krayt

Comment: I see you have a nice list, so I'll just leave this here - [Tavion Axmis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tavion_Axmis) - Legends

Comment: @SBI - yes, existing older answers had her so I skipped

Comment: Did you mention Darth Bane's apprentice and Ventress from canon?

Comment: From EU/Legends lets also not forget Darth Talon and Darth Malady.

Comment: +1. Also just a note to others that Daala, Isard, and Mara Jade have a lot of EU books around them, too, so they aren't just minor EU characters.

Comment: Might be worth noting that (SPOILERS FOR A 12 YEAR OLD GAME) Bastilla falls to the Dark Side in KOTOR 1. If we're including Darth Traya/Kreia might as well throw in a footnote. Also Juhani who IIRC can either be redeemed or turned to the Dark Side as well.

Comment: I thought Aurra Sing was cannon, since she was in the Clone Wars series.

Comment: @RavenM - revamped to include Lucas canon section just for her. Thx!

Comment: @DVK Wouldn't she be Disney Cannon, since the Clone Wars is DC, at least according to Star Wars Rebels where we see Ashoka from Clone Wars?

Comment: @RavenM - I like to separate the two just out of OCD :) Lucas canon is a proper subset of Disney canon, excluding post-Lucas stuff

Comment: EU also has Darth Zannah, apprentice to Darth Bane, who instituted the Rule of Two.

Comment: @Thunderforge - that was actually who I had in mind when I said "more in KOTOR" in my aside. But I'm not an Old Republic expert, so I outsourced that to another answer :)

Comment: Darth Zannah isn't KOTOR (or technically, even the Old Republic era). KOTOR comics & games happened around 4000 BBY and The Old Republic MMO around 3500 BBY. Darth Bane did his stuff in 1000 BBY and establishing the Rule of Two is officially the delineation between the Old Republic Era and the Rise of the Empire era according to Lucasfilm's classifications.

Comment: @Thunderforge - and now you know why I said i'm not an expert :))))

Comment: You're missing the [female Changeling bounty hunter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Zam_Wesell) that tried to kill Padme in Ep II

Comment: @CreationEdge - I'm not sure it rises up to the level of a "villain". merely working to kill the protagonist (especially no orders) makes one an antagonist, not a villain.

Answer (score 17):

Asajj Ventress was a Sith apprentice to Count Dooku during The Clone Wars for most of the series, until she realized he was playing her so she became a rogue force-wielding mercenary-type.

Comment: Ok, that was cool watching!

Comment: She turned good in the end though.

Answer (score 14):

### Canon

There is an entire order of female dark side users called the [Nightsisters](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nightsisters). A prominent Nightsister was [Mother Talzin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Talzin), who was Darth Maul's mother.

[image: Talzin]

[Asajj Ventress]]3] was also at one time a Nightsister and was later a Sith apprentice to Count Dooku.

[image: Asajj Ventress]

### Legends

In addition to the female, Force-sensitive villains from Legends mentioned in other answers, the following characters also fit your criteria:

- [Darth Cognus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Cognus) was an assassin who worked for Darth Bane (who is canon) and his apprentice Darth Zannah (also female, but Legends-only) before becoming Darth Zannah's apprentice.
- [Darth Zash](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Zash), who attempted to take over the body of her apprentice in order to prolong her life; this apprentice survived the attempt and became [Darth Nox](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Nox).
- [Atris](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Atris) was a Jedi who slowly turned to the dark side.

Comment: "dark side user" != "villian", per se.

Comment: @Raphael true, but last sentence of question suggests that OP is mainly interested in force wielders.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Knights of the Old Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic)

<sup>If you consider playing this game and haven’t done so, be advised that some of the following spoilers are central to its story.</sup>

- You can decide to play the player character female and villainous.
- The main villain on Dantooine is a fallen female Jedi called Juhani.

  > You can turn Juhani light again and become one of your companions.
- One of the instructors of the Sith academy on Korriban is a female Twi’lek called Yuthura.
- > Bastila will eventually turn to the dark side and become a short-time villain.
- > Revan – former Dark Lord and “founder” of the current incarnation of the Sith and responsible for the mess you are trying to fix – has the same gender as the player character […]

  ---

  > […] because the player character **was** Revan, before the Jedis wiped her mind.

Comment: If you can expand this to include all KOTOR timeline, that'd be great </office_space>. I'll link ot your answer from mine since I don't know much about Old Republic canon

Answer (score 3):

Darth Bane story line introduced two female Darksiders:

- [Githany](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Githany), former Jedi
- [Zannah](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah), Bane apprentice

These characters were first introduced in [Star Wars: Jedi vs. Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_vs._Sith) comic books and then re-imagined and expanded in [*Darth Bane* novels trilogy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Bane_trilogy).

Githany and Zannah are considered Legends now; Darth Bane spectre appeared in final episode of *Star Wars: Clone Wars* animated series, so he is somewhat of a canon.

Answer (score 0):

From SWTOR the MMO you have quite a few villainous females.

Most notable beeing 2 of the most powerful Sith in the galaxy at that time.

- [Brontes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Brontes), also known as the "Architect of Fear", was a powerful female Sith sorceress and member of the Dread Masters.
- [Bestia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bestia), also known as the "Keeper of the Dread Seeds", was a member of the Dread Masters, powerful Sith sorcerers.

Then there is the "comical" [Darth Zash](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Zash)

Answer (score 0):

In the Empire Strikes Back one of the TIE pilots pursuing the Millenium Falcon is identified as Civé Rashon, a female who rejoices in the callsign Howlrunner.

In various Star Wars related tabletop and video games, her backstory has been filled in to fairly villanous proportions. She lead the elite Obsidian Squadron through several engagements, culminating in the Battle of Endor.

Comment: Could you post the highlights? So far, she doesn't sound entirely villainous :) Probably because I enjoyed playing TIE-fighter

Comment: @DVK In truth, there doesn't seem to be a lot more. I first heard of her via the X-Wing miniatures game which doesn't include a lot of back story. I had thought that as an elite Imperial pilot, she was worth mentioning on status alone.

Comment: Civé? Is she from Naboo?

Answer (score 0):

If you count all Imperial officers as villains then there are plenty.

The most senior that I know of from Disney canon is Moff Mors, who is introduced in the book *Lords of the Sith*.

It is interesting to note Moff Mors and other Imperial officers. The Star Wars universe is not sexist in any of the canon. The key *-ism* in Star Wars is *speciesism*. Many (but by no means all) Imperial officers are human, and non-human species, e.g. Twi'leks, Wookiees etc. are exploited for their worlds' resources or as slave labour.

**Edit: extra villainous added**

There was also Queen Karina, Queen of the Geonosians. She controlled an army of undead Geonosians and held Luminara hostage.

[image: Queen Karina]

Comment: Moff mors was most certainly NOT villainus. To do so, would require her to actually.... y'know, get off her lazy ass and *do something villainous*. She's absolutely too sybaritic to qualify (compare that to Sloane's active participation in atrocities)

Comment: That's a good point @DVK, which is why I made the caveat "If you count all Imperial officers as villains...". Ultimately she may be viewed as being a villain in the sense that she is complicit in the pacification of Ryloth. She also encourages the slave trade by having her green Twi'lek servents (they have to match the palace decor after all) as well as planning who-knows-what with the Hutts

Comment: @DVK I absolutely and vehemently disagree! If you need to be able to "get off [your] lazy ass" in order to be counted as a villain, then Jabba the Hutt wouldn't be a villain!! So... no, not a good argument.

Comment: @MrLister - name ONE villainous thing Mors did, other than molesting houseslaves? In contrast, Jabba's list goes on for pages (including literally squashing a baby Hutt to death after murdering said baby's parent)